# synchronization over http: rsync versus normal upload

Tags: http, rsync, processing-efficiency

I'm running file synchronization over HTTP. Both sides implement rsync. When synchronizing, for uploading I have two choices:

1. use a simple post request if:

   - the file to be uploaded does'nt exists on the remote side.
   - the file exists and is bigger than a certain value M.
2. else : perform rsync over get requests.

My question is: How can I determine the perfect value of M.

I'm certain that for a certain file size, performing simple upload is faster than performing rsync steps . Especially for multiple files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using rsync correctly, I'd bet that it's always faster, *especially* with multiple files.

Rsync is specially built to check differences between directory trees and update the target directory incrementatlly.

The following is a one-liner to keep in mind whenever you need to sync two directory trees.

```
rsync -av --delete /path/to/src /path/to/target
```

(also works over SSH, if necessary.)

Only keep in mind that rsync is picky about trailing slashes on directory paths.

Comment: I'm using rsync correctly. the point is, I really think that for a small file, uploading using a single post request is better than sending request to get the remote file rsync signature, processing rsync delta and then send another request for the rsycn patch. 
Don't you think so?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you're using rsync incorrectly. ;) In my experience, the overhead of rsync is very low, and I wouldn't mind it. And, HTTP uploads are also resource-heavy: Interpret and run a webserver script, write the file to /tmp/, move it to the final destination. Don't forget the overhead of HTTP requests, caused by their large headers.